SQLcl coloured output is not shown in GitLab pipeline job output
I am using coloured output to deploy changes using SQLcl to my database. When I run it locally it works fine:
# sql /nolog
> prompt "You have selected environment: @|blue,intensity_bold [ asdas ]|@"

Here's an output in MacOS:

However, when it is ran in GitLab pipeline job, it is shown without colours (expected to be blue):

I use colours to help release manager immediately highlight errors during deployment (if any). Now it is just a regular plain text.
I am aware of bash and ANSI escaped codes which can make output coloured, but then I have to put ugly things like \033[0;31m and \033[0m to source code which is difficult to maintain.
So maybe there are some settings in GitLab or I can somehow alter SQLcl output so that job picks up colours.
